# login takes long time

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, login

I am using Ubuntu   12.04  from past  12 days. In the beginning login was fast enough after I put the password it hardly takes 3 to 4 sec to enter in desktop, but now its taking like more that 40 sec to show desktop after entering password. whats the problem, is there any solution?

P.S there is only two programs (psensor and jupiter) that starts automatically after login.

boot.log

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda6: clean, 254544/3325952 files, 2133831/13285632 blocks
* Stopping Userspace bootsplash[164G[ OK ]
* Stopping Flush boot log to disk[164G[ OK ]
* Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon[164G[ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
* Starting bluetooth daemon[164G[ OK ]
* Starting network connection manager[164G[ OK ]
* Starting AppArmor profiles       [170G 
[164G[ OK ]
* Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[164G[ OK ]
* Starting CUPS printing spooler/server[164G[ OK ]
* Starting System V runlevel compatibility[164G[ OK ]
* Starting Bumblebee supporting nVidia Optimus cards[164G[ OK ]
* Starting LightDM Display Manager[164G[ OK ]
* Starting save kernel messages[164G[ OK ]
* Starting anac(h)ronistic cron[164G[ OK ]
* Starting ACPI daemon[164G[ OK ]
* Starting regular background program processing daemon[164G[ OK ]
* Starting deferred execution scheduler[164G[ OK ]
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
* Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon[164G[ OK ]
```

Comment: Have you checked /var/log/boot.log for error(s)/warning(s)/failure(s)

Comment: @pl1nk there is my boot.log

Comment: This oneliner will locate files modified less than 5 minutes ago and displays if there are errors,failures or warning.
`find /var/log/ -mmin -5 |xargs cat|egrep -i 'error|fail|warn'`

Comment: Can you post your: /var/log/Xorg.0.log ?

Comment: This bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/996791 affected me even on Ubuntu (not Xubuntu). Could be this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your filesystems are full; this may cause many side effects.

Comment: that wont make any sort of difference on Ubuntu which uses EXT filesystem instead of FAT.